# Java Sorting "queue" list based on DateTime and Z Position (part of school project)

Tags: java, list, queue

For a school project i have a list of 50k containers that arrive on a boat. 
These containers need to be sorted in a list in such a way that the earliest departure DateTimes are at the top and the containers above those above them.
This list then gets used for a crane that picks them up in order.

I started out with 2 Collection.sort() methods:

1st one to get them in the right X>Y>Z order

```
Collections.sort(containers, new Comparator<ContainerData>() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ContainerData contData1, ContainerData contData2)
    {
        return positionSort(contData1.getLocation(),contData2.getLocation());
    }
});
```

Then another one to reorder the dates while keeping the position in mind:

```
Collections.sort(containers, new Comparator<ContainerData>() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ContainerData contData1, ContainerData contData2)
    {
        int c = contData1.getLeaveDateTimeFrom().compareTo(contData2.getLeaveDateTimeFrom());

        int p = positionSort2(contData1.getLocation(), contData2.getLocation());

        if(p != 0)
            c = p;

        return c;
    }
});
```

But i never got this method to work..

What i got working now is rather quick and dirty and takes a long time to process (50seconds for all 50k):

First a sort on DateTime:

```
Collections.sort(containers, new Comparator<ContainerData>() 
{
    @Override
    public int compare(ContainerData contData1, ContainerData contData2)
    {
        return contData1.getLeaveDateTimeFrom().compareTo(contData2.getLeaveDateTimeFrom());
    }
});
```

Then a correction function that bumps top containers up:

```
containers = stackCorrection(containers);

private static List<ContainerData> stackCorrection(List<ContainerData> sortedContainerList)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sortedContainerList.size(); i++)
    {
        ContainerData current = sortedContainerList.get(i);

        // 5 = Max Stack (0 index)
        if(current.getLocation().getZ() < 5) 
        {   //Loop through possible containers above current
            for(int j = 5; j > current.getLocation().getZ(); --j) 
            {   //Search for container above
                for(int k = i + 1; k < sortedContainerList.size(); ++k)
                    if(sortedContainerList.get(k).getLocation().getX() == current.getLocation().getX())
                    {
                        if(sortedContainerList.get(k).getLocation().getY() == current.getLocation().getY())
                        {
                            if(sortedContainerList.get(k).getLocation().getZ() == j)
                            {   //Found -> move container above current
                                sortedContainerList.add(i, sortedContainerList.remove(k));
                                k = sortedContainerList.size();
                                i++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    return sortedContainerList;
}
```

I would like to implement this in a better/faster way. So any hints are appreciated. :)

Comment: 50K containers!?!  Either they are very small containers or carried on a ***very large ship***.  The record seems to be around 16,020  containers for the [CMA CGM Marco Polo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Polo_%28containership%29)!  I'm just sayin'..

Comment: 51670 to be precise, not my idea :P Its loaded from an XML a teacher made

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want to sort with a single `Comparator` that compares on all of the criteria. E.g.:

```
compareTo(other)        
    positionComparison = this.position.compareTo(other.position)
    if positionComparison != 0
        return positionComparison 
    return this.departureTime.compareTo(other.departureTime)
```